# Docker refuses to mount NFS share

Tags: docker, mount, nfs

I'm trying to mount an NFS(version 3) share, which exists on the host, into a docker container, but it's not working.

Example:

```
docker run -v /mnt/test001/:/mnt/test001/ hello-world
```

This mount is an NFS share with squashed root, which I suspect is the reason for this problem. Docker seems to run as root(that's what `ps -ef` shows me anyway).

Error message states:

> dockerd[...]: time="..." level=error msg="Handler for POST
>   /.../containers/.../start returned error: error while creating mount
>   source path '/mnt/.../': mkdir /mnt/.../: permission denied"

What is required here to allow for this mount to occur? Removing the root squash seems unsafe and overkill. Is it possible to allow my local root to have read rights, while still squashing root?

EDIT: The permissions were dwrxwrx---

The problem was that world/other didn't have read right.

As such the subdirectory I wanted to mount could not be read by my local root, as that root got squashed -> needed world/other rights and there were none.

Comment: what about `docker run -v /mnt/test001:/var/test001 hello-world` ?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you want mkdir -p?

Comment: maybe `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` can do some magic - but not recommended.

Comment: @dstromberg That's from docker's own output, so not a command I control.

Comment: @FrankNielsen I'll try, but that's the directory inside the container. It's the directory outside the container that's troubling. Root on host can't read it.

Comment: What are the permissions on the volume's root (e.g. output of `ls -ld /mnt/test001`)?

Comment: Yeah it turned out to be permissions.